# Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient Timeout Option

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Due to SSL certificate issue we are using "Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient" API in my app service layer.

I referred below sample for my project.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664

How can we implement the timeout option in "Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient" API

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a CancellationTokenSource with a timeout.

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(2000); //timeout
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://test.example.com", cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {

        }
```

Edit : 
With Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient you should use the AsTask() extension method :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource source = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource(2000);
try
{
    client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://example.com")).AsTask(source.Token);
}
catch(TaskCanceledException ex)
{

}
```

Comment: My mistake, the above sample is written using System.Net.Http.HttpClient. If you need to stick to Windows.Web.HttpClient, you may want to take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.filters.aspx

Comment: Same implementation available in "Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient" CancellationTokenSource.

Comment: Really? Cause GetAsync takes an HttpCompletionOption. I'm not able to pass a Token.

Comment: Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient is a WinRT class and returns a IAsyncOperation that is not a Task. Is shouldn't be a big deal since you have the AsTask extension method. (my initial answer is updated with a sample).